# Immediately hiding a button in rails 4 + jQuery + simple_form after confirmation dialogue box OK is clicked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, button, view, jquery-events

In one of my views I have this code:

```
 <%= simple_form_for upload,  :remote => true  do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => upload.id %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :job, :value => "parse"%>
<%if (upload.status == 0)%>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Delete Entry:\n#{upload.sourcedata_file_name} from Database", :class=>"add_data_button" %>
<%elsif (upload.status == 1)%>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Add \n#{upload.sourcedata_file_name}\n to Database",:confirm=> "Start File parsing?", :class=> "add_data_button" %>
<%elsif (upload.status == 2)%>
    <%= "File has already been added to DB" %>
<%elsif (upload.status == 3)%>
    <%= "File is currently being added to DB" %>
<%else %>
    <%= "File has been removed from server" %>
<%end%>
 <% end %>
```

Which renders something like this:

[image]

What happens is if the user presses OK on the dialogue box, the processing starts in the background on the server but the button still is visible. What Id like to do is if the user clicks OK immediately disable the button.

I know I can do this in JQuery. That is I can handle the on_confirm button OK click event, but I cannot find any sample code on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of following:

```
<%= f.button :submit, "Add \n#{upload.sourcedata_file_name}\n to Database",:confirm=> "Start File parsing?", :class=> "add_data_button" %>
```

change your button as:

```
<%= f.button :submit, "Add \n#{upload.sourcedata_file_name}\n to Database", :id=>'btn1' :class=> "add_data_button" %>
```

and in your JS file, do following:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
  if (confirm("Start File parsing?")) {
    $('#btn1').addClass('disabled hide').removeClass('show');
    // Write code to submit your form.
  } else {
    return false;
    // Ensure that your form doesn't gets submitted here.
  }
});
```

PS: I think that there might be multiple such forms on which you might be looping through, so instead of adding individual id's, you can add a class to submit buttons & bind the javascript event on that class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unforunately this is not working for me :( I cannot omit the :confirm=>"Start File parsing?" from the code. If I do not modal dialogue box pops up.